# how to completely sign out from google plus from different Activity in android?

Tags: android, google-plus, logout

I have implemented google plus in my application and when I sign in via google plus then my app show all the google account which are sync in my android device. My problem is that when I sign out from google plus and again sign in then my app doesn't ask for choose account(do not show all the google accounts sync in my android device), It only shows for the first time I install the application and my app directly sign in to the account I choose at the first time of login. I am attaching my logout code. I have spent lot of time on this issue but didn't find any solution.

```
private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (SignInActivity.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(SignInActivity.mGoogleApiClient);
        SignInActivity.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        SignInActivity.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
 }
```

Comment: For that u need to revoke the Google+ access. Check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: thanks for you reply I applied revoke google+ but still the issue remains 
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
 
     });}

Comment: did you managed to find a solution??revoke is not working

Comment: No I am still facing this issue. I left this to resolve at the end of my application

Comment: Whenever I find I will post it here

Comment: did find the solution??plzz post here

Comment: I did it but its not a proper solution. What I did is I setup google plus same as I setup for login and the revoked the access and it worked for me.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734567/separating-the-concerns-of-activity-and-googleapiclient/31734568#31734568